# Browser Extension: Prevent Web Site from Capturing Keyboard Shortcut

Tags: firefox-addon, google-chrome-extension, keyboard-shortcuts

My employer uses an issue tracking software (which shall remain nameless) that captures CTRL + C and triggers a "Create a new ticket" workflow. I just want to use CTRL + C like normal, to copy text from the page, without being jumped to a pop-up form element at the page header each time. This can be disabled globally, but I would like to be able to just turn it off for myself.

I don't yet know anything about browser extensions. What I would like to know is: can I write an extension for Chrome, an addon for Firefox, whatever, that will, at a url with a particular host, prevent CTRL + C from being hijacked in this annoying way? Does anything like this already exist (it must!!)? If not, what should I read to get started, where can I find samples of something similar?

Many thanks for any links/suggestions/snippets.

Comment: If you can live with using the mouse to copy you may be able to get around this pretty easily. Since a form pops up, select the text with your mouse, right click and hold down the mouse button, when the form pops up dismiss it with the keyboard (tab over to cancel and hit enter key), when the popup disappears release the mouse button and viola - right click menu appears with 'copy' enabled.

Comment: You may need to use this in the URL bar of your browser - paste it in and hit enter. You can even set it as a bookmark for convenience:
javascript:void(document.oncontextmenu=null)

Comment: There is no general solution - once the web application calls `preventDefault()` or `stopPropagation()` on an event this cannot be undone. So your extension (probably better a GreaseMonkey script) needs to manipulate the web application and for example remove the event listener it uses. But you need to take a look at the JavaScript code of the application and understand how it works.

Comment: Agreed with Wladimir Palant. Since you found the shortcut handler you can just change it to Ctrl+Alt+C

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove a javascript function with Greasemonkey](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15282714/remove-a-javascript-function-with-greasemonkey)