# Remove a javascript function with Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, function, greasemonkey

I visit a website with a javascript file in the head of the HTML

```
<script language="javascript" src="javscript.js"></script>
```

The code inside this file is:

```
// keypress management 
if (document.layers) document.captureEvents(Event.KEYPRESS)
function update(e) {        
    if (document.all) {             // Explorer
        if (event.keyCode==13) document.forms[0].submit();  // 13 = ENTER
        else if (event.keyCode==26) runHelp(hplk);          // 26 = CTRL+Z
        return;
    } else {                                                // mozilla
        if (e.which==13) document.forms[0].submit();        // 13 = ENTER
        else if (e.which==26) runHelp(hplk);                // 122 = CTRL+Z     
        return;         
    }
}
document.onkeypress=update;
```

I want to disable/remove/replace this function with Greasemonkey.

I tried it with

```
unsafeWindow.update = function(){}
```

with no result! (got no errors in the console)

is there a way to kill this function?

Comment: See if the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064035/greasemonkey-overriding-website-functions) works for you. Haven't used GreaseMonkey in awhile, but it seems to make sense.

Comment: Is this on Firefox 2, with older Greasemonkey, like your previous questions?

Comment: i tried the code and added alert('TEST'); the code would created in the head but it doesn't fire "test"

Comment: @BrockAdams nice to read you.. no its on new FF and GM :D

Comment: @BrockAdams but the old question :D *shame*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not clear that `update` is a global function.  If it isn't then that approach won't work.

But you can override the keypress handler with:

```
unsafeWindow.document.onkeypress = function(){};
```

---

---

For a general, high-powered way to selectively block, or replace, any JS (on Firefox), use [`@run-at document-start`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40run-at) and [the checkForBadJavascripts function](https://gist.github.com/2620135), like so:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _Replace select javascript on a page
// @include     http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require     https://gist.github.com/raw/2620135/checkForBadJavascripts.js
// @run-at      document-start
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/

checkForBadJavascripts ( [
    [   false,
        /document\.onkeypress\s*=\s*update/,
        function () {
            addJS_Node (myKeypressFunction.toString() );
            addJS_Node ('document.onkeypress = myKeypressFunction;');
        }
    ]
] );


function myKeypressFunction (evt) {
    /*  DO WHATEVER HERE BUT USE NO GREASEMONKEY FUNCTIONS INSIDE
        THIS FUNCTION.
    */
    console.log ("Keypress function fired.");
}
```

---

[See this answer, for more information on `checkForBadJavascripts`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10468821/331508)

Comment: I LOVE YOU BROCK ADAMS :D unsafeWindow.document.onkeypress = function(){}; works perfect :D included this part to the old script and works perfect! i hope this part is definitely finished :D i will test this next week on the terminal and let you know. than we can finish this part and drink a beer.. or two :D THANKS

Comment: can't use checkForBadJavascripts because the terminal has no internet-connection!

Comment: You're welcome!  Remember, Stack Overflow questions are not about a "part" of whatever project you are working on.  They are about a single, specific, programming problem.

Comment: It sounds like you don't need `checkForBadJavascripts` in this case.  If you did, and without an internet connection, you would just copy and paste the entire utility code into your script. It's fairly short.

Comment: Sorry! I know. Believe me... this Script drives me crazy and gave me some nightmares :D