# How can I use GreaseMonkey to give the browser back the "/" key?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, dotjs

Lots of web pages seem to use the <kbd>/</kbd> key for searching. I'd like to disable that because 100% of the time I want to use <kbd>/</kbd> to search in the page in FireFox.  Is there a way I can override this behavior with GreaseMonkey or dotjs?

The best public example of this is https://www.github.com/, also https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Issue+Tracking

Comment: Which "dotjs" are you using?  There's more than one thing by that name.  Are you trying to run this on Chrome, too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- If you set [`addEventListener()`<sup>Doc</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/EventTarget.addEventListener) on `window` and use "event capture", you will catch 99% of what the page tries to do.  (Not counting plugins like Flash)
- You can't be sure if the page fires off of `keydown`, `keyup`, `keypress`, or some combination, so intercept `keydown` (the typical event used) and `keyup`.  But, if the page fires off of `keypress`, then blocking the event may require [this kind of technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15283597/331508).  This is because the `keypress` event, on `<body>`, bubbles up to trigger Firefox's in-page search, but there is no way to (re)trigger that search from javascript (for security).

  Fortunately, your two sample sites do not require any drastic measures.
- Event constants, like `DOM_VK_SLASH` are great, but they are still pretty much Firefox-only.  From this question's tags (dotjs), it is not clear if you mean for this to work on Chrome, too.

Putting it all together, this complete script works:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _Nuke the forward slash on select pages
// @include     https://github.com/*
// @include     https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/*
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/

//-- "true" tells the listener to use capture mode.
window.addEventListener ('keydown',  blockSlashKey, true);
window.addEventListener ('keyup',    blockSlashKey, true);
/*-- Don't block keypress on window or body, this blocks the default
    page-search, too.
window.addEventListener ('keypress', blockSlashKey, true);
*/

function blockSlashKey (zEvent) {
    var FORWARD_SLASH   = 191;  // For keydown and keyup
    var ASCII_SLASH     = 47;   // For keypress

    if (    zEvent.which === FORWARD_SLASH
        || (zEvent.which === ASCII_SLASH  &&  zEvent.type == "keypress")
    ) {
        zEvent.stopPropagation();
    }
}
```

---

Note:  This script seems to work well on the two sites you listed, in both Chrome and Firefox.  And, it will not stop the typing of <kbd>/</kbd> into inputs or textareas.  But, there is a tiny chance that it might cause some sites to not fire other events on the <kbd>/</kbd> key.

If that happens, then use checks like `zEvent.target.nodeName == "BODY"` to restrict `blockSlashKey()`'s operation.

Comment: Ok, I'm a firefox user.  I assumed that would be clear since / is the search button in FF, but in chrome the search button is CTRL-F.  Anyway, sadly this doesn't seem to work for me at all.  While it does correctly fire (I checked by adding an alert to the function body) it does not stop / from focussing the site specific search box on github.  I'm going to restart FF and see if greasemonkey works better than dotjs, but I kinda doubt it will.  (Worked for the wiki though!)

Comment: Only seems to work in greasemonkey, but hey, it works everywhere!  I'll file a bug with the dotjs guy but I am happy for now :)

Comment: What most people call "dotjs" is a tool for Chrome.  That's why I was asking.  If you link to the "dotjs" you are using, maybe I can see a problem (no promises).  Also, don't put alerts in event listeners in Greasemonkey.  They tend to break the handler.  Use `console.log()` instead.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's usually a chrome addon. Sorry about that.  The source is here: https://github.com/rlr/dotjs-addon

Comment: Also, I found a site it doesn't seem to work on: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa  If you have ideas on how to make it work please let me know or update your post.

Comment: Unfortunately, [the second jenkins site](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa) is one of those that uses `keypress`.  As stated in the answer, you need to use techniques like in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15283597/331508) to surgically alter such keyboard-shortcut grabbers. ... **However**, in this case, if you don't care about any of the KB shortcuts, and you want that page to operate noticeably faster, just use *AdBlock Plus* to block `https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/rest/api/1.0/shortcuts/*/shortcuts.js`.

Comment: If you don't want to block all of that page's ham-handed, kb shortcuts and you can't get `checkForBadJavascripts()` to work on that page, open a new GM question and I promise I'll give it a go.

Comment: Thank you! To make it work with Violentmonkey on GitHub, see https://violentmonkey.github.io/2018/11/23/inject-into-context/

Comment: Thanks, @woky .  Try just changing the `@grant` to `none` instead. Theoretically, that should make it work for Violentmonkey too, but I'll let you test it.

Answer (score -1):

This Greasemonkey script work on Firefox

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Disable slash key on page
// @namespace   test
// @include     https://github.com/*
// @include     https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/*
// @grant       none
// @version     1
// ==/UserScript==

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === event.DOM_VK_SLASH) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
}, true);
```

Comment: Interesting, it doesn't seem to work with dotjs.  I wonder if there is some weird loading issue where it doesn't get included early enough...

Comment: Ok so this works on that wiki, but not on github?  You have to be logged in to see the search part of github.

Comment: Also work on github, do you notice the @include line? Maybe you should add more to activate the script.